# Split a string into lines?

Tags: c#

Here is code;

```
        foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.xml"))
        {
            string test = getValuesOneFile(file.ToString());

            result.Add(test);

            Console.WriteLine(test);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        File.WriteAllLines(filepath + @"\MapData.txt", result);
```

Here is what it looks like in the console;

```
[30000]
total=5
sp 0 -144 152 999999999
sp 0 -207 123 999999999
sp 0 -173 125 999999999
in00 1 -184 213 999999999
out00 2 1046 94 40000
```

Here is how it looks like in the text file (when written at end of loop).

```
[30000]total=5sp 0 -144 152 999999999sp 0 -207 123 999999999sp 0 -173 125 999999999in00 1 -184 213 999999999out00 2 1046 94 40000
```

I need it to write the lines in the same style as the console output.

Comment: What type is `result`?

Comment: Open the file with [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), and go to View > Show Symbol > Show All Characters. If you see [**LF**] at the end of each line, but no [**CR**], you have Unix-style line endings which do not work in Windows Notepad. If you do not see either [**CR**] nor [**LF**], then something is incorrect with the way you are using `File.WriteAllLines()` because it is not actually writing the line endings into the file.

Comment: @SpikeX, I see this: https://hostr.co/file/9RHXCN286Uvb/Untitled.png Any solution?

Comment: result = List<string> result = new List<string>();

Comment: I get a "File not found" when trying to view that link @user3457618. Try http://imgur.com/.

Comment: I already fixed the problems Spike, no worries! Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than `WriteAllLines` You'll probably want to just write the text manually:

```
string textToWrite = "";
foreach (var res in result)
{
  textToWrite += res.Replace("\r","").Replace("\n",""); //Ensure there are no line feeds or carriage returns
  textToWrite += "\r\n"; //Add the Carriage Return
}
File.WriteAllText(filepath + @"\MapData.txt", textToWrite)
```

Comment: this does nothing, same result :*(

Comment: What's the result in Notepad++?

Comment: The result in Notepad++ is it being one long line with CR & LF: https://hostr.co/file/zPmXBdMnwbMd/Untitled.png

Comment: If you are concatenating a string more than four to six times, you should use `StringBuilder`, as it's more performant. Just FYI.

Answer (score 2):

`WriteAllLines` is going to separate each of the values with the environments new line string, however, throughout the history of computers a number of possible different characters have been used to represent new lines.  You are looking at the text file using some program that is expecting a different type of new line separator.  You should either be using a different program to look at the value of that file; one that either properly handles this type of separator (or can handle any type of separator), you should be configuring your program to expect the given type of separator, or you'll need to replace `WriteAllLines` with a manual method of writing the strings that uses another new line separator.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is definitely how you are looking for newlines in your output.  `Environment.NewLine` will get inserted after each string written by `WriteAllLines`.

I would recommend opening the output file in NotePad++ and turn on View-> ShowSymbol-> Show End of Line to see what end of line characters are in the file.  On my machine for instance it is `[CR][LF]`  (Carriage Return / Line Feed) at the end of each line which is standard for windows.

Comment: `WriteAllLines` should be introducing newlines.  It's what differentiates it from `WriteAllText`.  After this change the code now has two newlines at the end of each line.

Comment: @Servy Source text needs to have "newlines" though. If it does not, WriteAllLines is mute.

Comment: @mxmissile No.  The whole *point* of `WriteAllLines` is that it adds the newlines for you.  There would be no reason to use the method if it didn't.

Comment: I added comments above. I don't understand how to fix this :(

Comment: Can you check what `Environment.NewLine` returns on your system?  I'm trying to come up with a scenario where the output you listed gets created from `WriteAllText`

Comment: @Servy noticed result was a "collection" too late, you are correct. MikeH lol thanks! Too late for me to edit though, ouch!

Comment: Anyone know how to fix this issue?